# How to add hollow shapes to an image?

Tags: images

How to add hollow shapes to an image? Like in LibreOffice while creating a document I can add some auto shapes using insert menu, is there any way to do it using some image editing tools, specially using gimp?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some sample of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MattiaGalati like here https://imgur.com/a/NXZDQ

Comment: I don't think GIMP has such a feature, but personally I wouldn't use it to do so: when adding a "shape" to a canvas, it's almost sure you want to manipulate its size, ratio, fill and stroke which would requires at least an appropriate plugin in GIMP.

It's probably much more simple to create you shapes (also complex ones) in a software like inkscape and then import the result into GIMP, or otherwise import into inkscape the raster graphic from GIMP.

Comment: Define "hollow shape" please

Comment: @Scott 2D shapes with only outline or only with borders but not solid or opaque

Comment: Just a shape with **no** *fill*?

Comment: Well in Word, you'd draw a shape.. add a **line** but not add a fill, as @WELZ alludes to. I have no experience with LibreOffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"2D hollow shapes" are vectors with a stroke, and no fill. So, vector image editing software like Inkscape (which is free) or Illustrator (not free) is probably what you are looking for.  That's the kind of software graphic designers use for making logos, geometric designs, icons, line art, etc.

Most vector image editors have polygon, ellipse, and rectangle tools, for making basic shapes. Other shapes can be made by drawing them directly with the Bézier tool (or Pen tool), or joining shapes together using boolean operations such as Union, Difference, Division, etc.

GIMP is a raster image editor, which is a different kind of software and not really suited for that kind of thing, although GIMP does have a Path tool which can be used for making Bézier curves/paths which can be stroked, or filled. However, vector image editing software is easier and better for this.

Just one little warning: software like Inkscape or Illustrator has a fairly steep learning curve. However, luckily there are literally thousands of tutorials online for beginners.